# pass var from javascript innerhtml to python flask function

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, innerhtml

I am trying to use javascript to create a list of button, with click of each button, will call a python flask function and pass a string to that python function.
but error occur, "Bad Request, The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

below is the html code:

```
    <div style="color:red" id = "demo"></div>
    <script>
    var a = {{ dirs|tojson }};
    text = "";
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    var x = a[i];
    text +=  "<form action='/list_patient' method='post'> <button type='submit' name = 'button1' class='btn btn-default value='"+ x +"'>"+a[i]+"</button> </form>";
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

    </script>
```

below is flask python function:

```
    @app.route('/list_patient',methods=['POST'])
    def list_patient():
        string = request.form['button1']
```